# array.length do not increment on push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I push strings to an array and display the elements in a textarea. The array populates as expected when `onchange` is triggered, and then I need to get the number of elements in the array, but the `IDarr.length` stays fixed on 2. Can anybody advise me on the error? Here’s my code:

Script:

```js
function UpdBttn(ct){
    var array = document.getElementById('array').innerHTML;
    var IDarr = [array];

    IDarr.push(ct);

    document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = IDarr;

    alert(IDarr.length);
}
```

Receiving textarea:

```
<textarea id="array"></textarea><br>
```

Input text (from databaseloop) to populate `IDarr` `onchange`:

```
<input Type="text" id="event<%=ct%>" value="<%=events(dates)%>" onchange="UpdBttn(this, '<%=ct%>')">
```

Comment: Well of course it stays fixed on two. You create it in the function with a single element in it, then add another element to it, and then log the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your variable outside of the function to prevent it from initializing each time you call the function try this:

```
var IDarr = [];
function UpdBttn(ct){
  var array = document.getElementById('array').innerHTML;

  IDarr.push(ct);

  document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = IDarr;

  alert(IDarr.length);
}
```

Comment: And what if you push two items instead of one. Your `innerHTML` won't consider this as two separate items.

Comment: It does not seem that this is possible, at least in this implementation. But you are right in that case there is a need to `split` them and make 2 separate pushes. Nonetheless the variable needs to be outside the function as I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but you might do something like this:

```
function UpdBttn(ct){

  var array = document.getElementById('array').innerHTML;
  var IDarr = array.split(',');

  IDarr.push(ct);

  document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = IDarr.join(',');

  alert(IDarr.length);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, define `IDarr` outside of the function rather than inside, and append to it and render it inside the function

Comment: Since we know the HTML element with ID `array` is a `textarea`, you should use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text inside it, not [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: I believe that he added the `textArea` bit of his question after I posted this answer. So yes, by all means use the appropriate API for wherever you're getting your text content from.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` returns a string. So when you retrieve array using `var array = document.getElementById('array').innerHTML;` it is single string. So you have one element that is  string in your array and after pushing another element it become two.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const divContent = document.querySelector('#array').innerHTML
    const idArr = [divContent];
    console.log(idArr);
     
    idArr.push('lorem');
    document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = idArr;
    // The length will be same
    console.log(idArr.length);
});
```

```html
 <div id="array">Item1, Item2</div>
 <button>Click Me</button>
```

I am not really sure about how your `innerHTML` (Note - If you need only the contents between tag, better use `textContent`) looks. But you need to convert your `textContent` from string to array.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const divContent = document.querySelector('#array').innerHTML
  const idArr = [...divContent.split(',')];
  
  console.log(idArr);

  idArr.push('lorem');
  document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = idArr;
  console.log(idArr.length);
});
```

```html
<div id="array">Item1,Item2</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is wrong. when use create var IDarr = [array];
you always create a new array with one element. So when you push output array is same 2 for all the time. If you trying to implement the char counter functionality. Please user string, not an array.

Wrong:

```
var arr = ['s']
console.log(arr.length) // 1
console.log(arr) //s
arr.push('e')
console.log(arr.length) // 2
console.log(arr) //se
//next time
var arr = ['se']
console.log(arr.length) // 1
console.log(arr) //se
arr.push('e')
console.log(arr.length) // 2
console.log(arr) //se,e
```

Correct Way:

```
var text = 's'
console.log(text.length) // 1
console.log(text) //s
text = text + 'e'
console.log(text.length) // 2
console.log(text) //se
//next time 
var text = 'se'
console.log(text.length) // 2
console.log(text) //se
text = text + 'ee'
console.log(text.length) // 3
console.log(text) //see
```